# Visual Studio 2013 add windows phone emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, hyper-v

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional on Windows 8.1. I created a custom windows phone virtual machine in Hyper-V. However, when I opened my application in Visual Studio, it doesn't list my virtual machine. I have installed Windows Phone 8.1 Update and Emulators. The custom virtual machine is based off one of those emulators. The predefined Phone emulators are showing up in Visual Studio. However, my custom virtual machine is not showing up. So, how do I modify Visual Studio to detect my windows phone virtual machine and run the application on it ?

Another alternative that I am exploring is to set a specific checkpoint in Hyper-V as the default image for a Windows Phone 8.1 emulator image. The following MSDN link says that we can set a checkpoint as the default image.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn632391.aspx#BKMK_checkpoints

However, I do not see that window anywhere in Hyper-V. Can somebody please let me know if I need to download any additional software ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to run your app on your phone, before that you need to install Windows Phone 8.1 Update and Emulators from,

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43719

Comment: Farah, I have installed the Windows Phone 8.1 Update and Emulators. The emulator that I have created is a modified version of one of those 8.1 emulators.

Comment: @Max You can give a look at this link. Might help you [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/196158/how-to-create-and-run-virtual-machines-with-hyper-v/)

Answer (score 0):

The referenced checkpoint window is in the emulator, not in hyper-v itself.

Run the emulator, expand the tools menu (the >> icon at the bottom of the tools bar) and you should find the checkpoint tab there.